# How to use each element of vector in a function to create data frames, then append all the data frames

Tags: r, function, dataframe, rbind

I'd like to use the value in each row of one column of a dataframe (filenames) as an argument in a function. This function imports data from a .ods file that has a matching filename, and extracts information into a new dataframe.

I'd like to apply the function to each filename in the table 'filenames', thus creating about 50 data frames. I want to append each of these data frames, I'd imagine using rbind, to get one dataframe out at the end.

I've written it for one filename, but am struggling to work out how to write it as a function that repeats iteratively through the list of filenames, then appends the resulting dataframes.

I've written an example below, any help very gratefully received!

```
map <- data.frame(well = c("A01", "A02", "A03", "B01", "B02", "B03", "C01", "C02", "C03", "A01", "A02", "A03", "B01", "B02", "B03", "C01", "C02", "C03"),
                  plate = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

filenames <- data.frame(filenames = c("file1", "file2", "file3"),
                        plate = c(1, 1, 2))

firstdatetime <- as.POSIXct("2020-03-26 07:56:20 GMT")

activefile <- as.vector(filenames[1,1])
data <- data.frame(read.ods(activefile))

###for the purposes of this example, a sample data file is created below
data <- data.frame(datetime = "2020-03-26 13:04:38 GMT", one = c(2,4,6), two = c(4, 6, 6), three = c(5, 5, 2))
###

plate <- as.numeric(filenames$plate[match(activefile, filenames$filenames)])
datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime[1])
time <- as.numeric(difftime(strptime(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                            strptime(firstdatetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
temp <- plate
df <- subset(map, plate == temp)
df$filename <- activefile
df$time <- time

a570 <- data.frame(data[,-1])
a570 <- as.vector(t(a570))
df$a570 <- a570

###
#then repeat this for each filename in 'filenames', adding each dataframe to the bottom of the one before. The final output would be one big data frame.
```

Comment: You have a lot going on in the code you've posted here. I want to make sure of something: You have a vector of file names (in a data frame column), and **all** you need to do is read those files into data frames and row bind them, right? Or is there something else you're trying to accomplish in all that code?

Comment: The real files I'm reading into data are more complicated than the example I've given. I need to extract and reformat a few parts of each file to create each data frame. I tried to simplify in the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hello_friend's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480654/8386140) shows what to do if you simply need to read in the files and `rbind()` them. To me, this is not interesting as it is obviously a duplicate.

However, I'm not sure if it's a duplicate when you need to do some pre-processing first (although to some it may seem an obvious extension). What you need to do is make a *function* to pre-process.

I've simplified your example further and have two ODS files, `file1.ods` with data

```
a b
1 1
```

and `file2.ods` with data

```
a b
2 2
```

And for pre-processing I'll use the simpler task of adding 3 to the first value. We could do the following:

```
library(readODS)

filenames <- c("file1.ods", "file2.ods")

foo <- function(filename) {
    res <- read_ods(filename)
    res[1, 1] <- res[1, 1] + 3
    return(res)
}

do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, foo))

#   a b
# 1 4 1
# 2 5 2
```

You can of course make the pre-processing done in `foo()` as complex as you like (including setting names if need be, dealing with dates as I think you're doing, etc.).

Comment: Excellent, thanks, this looks promising. I'll try applying to my real data and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution to the problem of reading iteratively and rbinding into a single df:

```
# Filenames data provided by user: filenames => data.frame
filenames <- data.frame(filenames = c("file1", "file2", "file3"),
                        plate = c(1, 1, 2))
# Empty list to store each file: df_list => list
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(filenames$filenames)))
# Read in files and name them appropriately: df_list => list
df_list <- setNames(lapply(filenames$filenames, function(x){
                        data.frame(read.ods(x))}), filenames$filenames)
# rbind into a single object: df => data.frame
df <- do.call("rbind", df_list)
```

If you want to store the filename as a vector to match on later:

```
filenames <- data.frame(filenames = c("file1", "file2", "file3"),
                        plate = c(1, 1, 2))
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(filenames$filenames)))

df_list <- setNames(mapply(
  cbind,
  "filename" = filenames$filename,
  lapply(filenames$filenames, function(x) {
    data.frame(read.ods(x))
  }),
  filenames$filenames
))

df <- do.call("rbind", df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get "Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument" when I try and run the function. I've tried replacing filenames with true ones, but to no avail

Comment: @Mike are you using the entire filepath with the extension?